# window different from PC to Mac

Tags: windows, macos, matlab, matlab-guide

A professor gave me a matlab code written on a PC (with OS windows). On his computer the window was well placed and everything was able to read and to perform. Now on my Mac the window (the window appears after clicking Run) seems quite different. All the items from the guide are moved. Even if I place them in an appropriate order in the guide-window those problems still exist.

See attached the window when it's runned on my Mac. 
[image: matlab_problem_shown_on_Mac]

In the guide it looks like this.
[image: how it looks like in the guide]

On the PC it looked quite similar like in the guide (when I opened the code from the PC the first time  on my Mac, in the guide all the items were moved around as well. Like it's appearing now in the Run-window)

First there was a normalized function in the code to make sure it will fit with every monitor but even without the normalized function the problems still exist.

I'd like to understand what I have to do to fix this presentation problem with Matlab on my Mac.

Comment: You see, that it isn't running right. Don't understand the "So?". 

I'd like to understand how to fix the problem. I'd like to run the program without having the buttongroup outside of the window and not seeing the pushbutton neither the textbox. That's not really what it should like referring to the code. On the PC it worked pretty well. On the Mac it isn't looking the same.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited data provided I would urge you to look at the properties of the single UI elements. Most likely those are positioned not relative to the figure but absolutely using e.g. pixels. Depending on the resolution of the screen, this might produce the results above (Apple's retina comes to mind).

Comment: yes, apple retina is my Mac. Didn't know what more data I should have provided. Will try to follow your suggestion.

Comment: Update: Position is shown like this: x 13,667; y 61.76. Can't change it. Can just change FontUnits from inches to normalized/pixels and so on.

Comment: Well, the problem might be fixed pixel values. Unless calculated properly at runtime this is a bad idea, since you never know at which resolutions  the application is going to run. Depending on what Matlab version you are using, retina will not help the issue. AFAIK Matlab had some problems running on retina until recently. Maybe playing with the Mac's resolution might help, but this is no permanent solution. Someone has to look at the code and use proper positioning, e.g. by using normalized units (i.e. the screen has a height and width of 1, and you position at values relative to that).